# Refinement of group by using timestamp in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say we have table `master` with columns `column1`, `column2`, `column3` and `timestamp` and a query

```
select
  column1,
  column2,
  count(*) as CNT
from
  master
group by
  column1,
  column2
```

Now I would like to refine the above partition as follows. We sort each group by timestamp from oldest to youngest. In my case each group must then be of the form

```
column3 | column3 = 'A' | timestamp
X         FALSE           t1
A         TRUE            t2
A         TRUE            t3
Y         FALSE           t4
Z         FALSE           t5
A         TRUE            t6
A         TRUE            t7
A         TRUE            t8
A         TRUE            t9
```

That is, `ti > ti+1` and each group starts with `FALSE`. In the query I would like to further partition every group into seperate groups as follows. Given the single example group from above, we should get 3 groups:

```
column3 | column3 = 'A' | timestamp
X         FALSE           t1
A         TRUE            t2
A         TRUE            t3
```

```
column3 | column3 = 'A' | timestamp
Y         FALSE           t4
```

```
column3 | column3 = 'A' | timestamp
Z         FALSE           t5
A         TRUE            t6
A         TRUE            t7
A         TRUE            t8
A         TRUE            t9
```

That is, every group starts with a `FALSE` and is followed by all consecutive `TRUE`s until the next `FALSE` in the group. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is called **gaps and islands**. For some reason I have mental block on this: I have to google how do it every time and therefore am just posting this as a comment. But the name of the problem is correct, and that will be enough you can find the rest of the answer on your own.

Comment: This question does not compile. If you group by timestamp, by definition each group only contains one timestamp.

The order of results depend on the order by and by the data in the database. You cannot use a SELECT to guarantee that a result starts with 'FALSE' and with the smallest timestamp. You'll have to ensure that your data looks like that. 

"I would like to further partition every group into separate groups as follows". Again not sure what you mean here. Each group already consists of different values for the three columns, by definition.

Comment: @JensSchauder I didn't group by timestamp but ordered in every group by timestamp.

Comment: Please provide table structure and example data and desired result for that example data.

Comment: If you cannot sort a group. A group is just a single row.

Comment: Sure. I thought it was clear what I meant but I will provide more example data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is about the table that you showed. Can suggest the following solution. I made a table similar to yours:

```
 column3 | A |     time_stamp
---------+---+---------------------
 X       | f | 2021-01-01 00:00:00
 A       | t | 2021-01-01 02:00:00
 A       | t | 2021-01-01 03:00:00
 Y       | f | 2021-01-01 06:00:00
 Z       | f | 2021-01-01 07:00:00
 A       | t | 2021-01-01 04:00:00
 A       | t | 2021-01-01 08:30:00
 A       | t | 2021-01-01 08:45:00
 A       | t | 2021-01-01 07:15:00
```

WITH vars contains two subqueries. In CASE  "A" = FALSE  I set value it to 1 where FALSE, otherwise 0. The result is the "case" column. In the following subquery, the cumulative sum of "case" is calculated. As a result, we get the "total" column.

```
WITH vars as (
SELECT *,
    SUM("case") OVER (ORDER BY time_stamp asc) as total
FROM 
(
 SELECT "column3","A","time_stamp",
 CASE WHEN "A" = FALSE THEN 1
 WHEN "A"= TRUE THEN 0
 ELSE 0
 END
 FROM master
)
pseudo1
)

SELECT * 
FROM vars
--WHERE total = 1
;
```

Get the following data:

```
 column3 | A |     time_stamp      | case | total
---------+---+---------------------+------+-------
 X       | f | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |    1 |     1
 A       | t | 2021-01-01 02:00:00 |    0 |     1
 A       | t | 2021-01-01 03:00:00 |    0 |     1
 A       | t | 2021-01-01 04:00:00 |    0 |     1
 Y       | f | 2021-01-01 06:00:00 |    1 |     2
 Z       | f | 2021-01-01 07:00:00 |    1 |     3
 A       | t | 2021-01-01 07:15:00 |    0 |     3
 A       | t | 2021-01-01 08:30:00 |    0 |     3
 A       | t | 2021-01-01 08:45:00 |    0 |     3
```

If we uncomment the line " --WHERE total = 1", we get the following rows:

```
 column3 | A |     time_stamp
---------+---+----------------
 X       | f | 2021-01-01 00:0
 A       | t | 2021-01-01 02:0
 A       | t | 2021-01-01 03:0
 A       | t | 2021-01-01 04:0
```